# change "missing attachment" text functions.php

Tags: filters

WordPress core file: `wp-includes/post-template.php` has this text "Missing Attachment" that i want to change with "-". The problem is that when WordPress upgrades, the file is changed back to the old "Missing Attachment" text.

So, are there any filters I can use in my `functions.php` to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never change a core file. This message is called by the function wp_get_attachment_link(). For this singular message this function does not apply a filter, but it return the string as value, which can help. You can simple identify where in your theme this function is called and change it return, like:

```
$result = wp_get_attachment_link();
if ($result == 'Missing Attachment')
  echo '-';
else
  echo $result;
```

Comment: perfect tks alot

Comment: Compare agains `__( 'Missing Attachment' )` which will account for localized texts.